# Syntax Error : with tf.Session() as sess: File "<ipython-input-20-b0b30aac112f>",

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I tried to run the following code, but got the syntax error

```html
import tensorflow as tf
p = tf.constant("Hello")
h = tf.constant("world!")
ph = p + h
with tf.Session() as sess:
 sess.run(ph)
print(sess.run(ph))
```

The error is like the one in image below:
[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWv9T.png)

Comment: Not sure what is happening with ipython. However you'll want to just have one `sess.run(ph)` call. This returns a python value that you can print, etc. And any `sess.run()` call needs to happen in the `with tf.Session()` block. When I made these changes your code ran fine on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the print statement inside the with block

```html
import tensorflow as tf
p = tf.constant("Hello")
h = tf.constant("world!")
ph = p + h
with tf.Session() as sess:
 print(sess.run(ph))
```

As for the error, you were probably trying to run the code interactively in ipython and might have hit shift+Enter while running the with statement. Ipython complained because it did not find anything inside the block